# Outlook starts freezes in randon while using custom addin

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

We have developed custom outlook addin in c# 3 years back and the addin worked without any problems. Tasks of our addin are:

1. open a form and fill some data.
2. Connect to Sharepoint and call rest service.
3. Service will send email in the background which uses ExchangeOnline service.

When users started using this addin, it starts to freeze the outlook in all 3 places randomly. I could not find out any errors in the evenviewer also. I tried the Recovery assistant and it does not solve the problem. It happens to all users who are using the addin. Yesterday, what I noticed in my outlook is. It freezes for me only when OneNote is open.

Is there any changes in outlook recently? Is there any other location where I can see more errors.

Comment: Try the event viewer logs. Salesforce has a nice help article on how to see those logs.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269610&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @thewindev, thank you for your help. I tried to optimize the addin with ReleaseComObject but still my addin freezes outlook when other Microsoft addins are added to outlook. I have listed 3 addins (Azure Protection and Send to Bluetooth and Microsoft OneNote Notes addins) which makes outlook freeze when I add them while our addin is running. After optimizing, the big problem which I see is the addin is disabled every morning when we start outlook. I set it to enable always but still it is inactive.

Comment: So if you disable those 3 addins, your addin works ok without being disabled? We're currently having a similar issue with the Salesforce addin but I haven't been able to find out what's the problem yet.

Comment: there are two issues for my addin. If I disable other addins, outlook is not frozen when my addin is used. Other issue is, on start up, my addin is always disabled. I tried to set the Resiliency value to 1 for my addin. I am testing now.